# How can I downgrade my ionic cli to the previous version, I had?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

The recent version is `3.2.0` and I'm facing lot's of issues with it like the `ionic serve` command not working.

Answer (score 33):

**`npm install -g ionic@version_number`**

ex: if you want to install ionic 2.5.0,

**`npm install -g ionic@2.5.0`**

edit: to list all versions of ionic, **`npm info ionic`**

Answer (score 14):

You can downgrade to your old version by running below command:

```
npm install -g ionic@3.9.2
```

Get your version here

[IONIC CLI VERSIONS](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 4):

You may try uninstalling it first: `npm uninstall -g ionic`
then install it again with the version that you want to install `npm install -g ionic@x.x.x`

then check ionic version with `ionic --version` you may need to restart your terminal to get the latest version running

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, uninstall the current version:

```
    npm uninstall -g ionic
```

then, install the version you want :

```
   npm install -g ionic@"the version for example @3.20.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do like this:

```
npm install -g ionic@3.1.0
```

[**Changelog**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it throws error while overwriting the existing files , so add `--force`

Ex, If you want to downgrade to version 3.20, run:
`npm i -g ionic@3.20 --force`

Answer (score 0):

I like prefer use version 6
`npm install @ionic/angular@6`

Comment: Why? What is the advantage of the other solutions provided here?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "... over the other solutions ....".